# Windowing to smooth signal

Tags: matlab

For matlab, i want to generate a sequence of hanning windows which are overlapping 50% for apply to my input signal. And for the overlapping parts between windows, I want to make it take its average e.g (x+y)/2 then only apply to my signal.How to generate the sequence of hanning window which gt average between them?Thank you.

Comment: 'help hanning; help movavg; help mean;

Comment: Are you sure you want to take the average of overlapping parts? This will produce discontinuities at middle of the first and last window.

Comment: Yes Deve.Is it possible to do so?or can I multiply my signal separately to hanning window and get the average after multiplied?but just how to put them in an array with the average.

Comment: @Thy Hint: you should use `@username` to notify others of comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script adds up shifted versions of Hanning windows that overlap 50%. All windows are scaled by 0.5 except the first and last window. Of the first window the second half is scaled by 0.5, of the last window the first half is scaled by 0.5.

```
% Length of input sequence
N = 600;
% Length of one Hanning window
L = 50;
% can be periodic or symmetric
sampling_flag = 'periodic';

all_windows = zeros(N, 1);
figure; hold all;
for k = 0:floor(2*(N-L)/L)
    current_window = hann(L, sampling_flag);
    if k == 0        
        current_window(L/2 + 1 : end) = current_window(L/2 + 1 : end) * 0.5;        
    elseif k == floor(2*(N-L)/L)
        current_window(1 : L/2) = current_window(1 : L/2) * 0.5;
    else
        current_window = current_window * 0.5;
    end
    all_windows = all_windows + [zeros(k*L/2, 1); current_window; zeros(N - L - k*L/2, 1)];
    plot([zeros(k*L/2, 1); hann(L); zeros(N - L - k*L/2, 1)]);
end
hold off;
figure;
plot(all_windows);
```

Answer (score 0):

When generating windows in Matlab, you can add the 'periodic' option.
Then, if you have a 50% overlap, two conseccutive windows will have their overlap equal to one.
As an example you can try:

```
w=hanning(100,'periodic');
x=w(1:50)+w(51:100);
unique(x)

ans =

    1.0000
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that the `periodic` option produces a periodic repetition of the window?

Comment: But I want the repetition of the hanning windows and every overlapping parts can plus up 2 points and divided by 2 so that no more overlapping and i can multiply to my signal.The x only get all 1 in value.

Comment: The "periodic" option does not repeat the window. But if you use the window before applying a Fourrier transform, it may be preferable to use "periodic".